# Reloading a JSON file on Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a function who update (reload) the content of a JSON file everytime this is modified.

I (obviuously) already load the file:

```
comandos = json.load(open('comandos.json'))
```

But everytime the json is updated, i have to kill the python process to do load it again.

**-- Update**

The script is in a loop, i'm using it as a Bot (conected to Telegram, listening for any commands from a user group).

In this case, when i 'release' new functions (new commands) i would like that the bot reload all the content on the file 'comandos.json' to get the new options on the Telegram channel.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** This solution reads the file many times but does not rely on a library and is platform independent.

Please give more detail!

Here is a solution you **could** use. Of course there are alternatives but I don't know the exact use case. I think you want to reload the file once it is modified.

```
def fileWatcher():
    global comandos, comandosText
    while True:
        f = open('comandos.json')
        content = f.read()
        f.close()
        if content != comandosText:
            print("File was modified! Reloading it...")
            comandos = json.loads(content)
            comandosText = content
        time.sleep(0.5) #Adjust this to get the best performance
```

Then later in your main code...

```
import time
import threading
import json
threading.Thread(target=fileWatcher).start()
```

This starts the file watcher asynchronously in the background and updates `comandos` once you updated the file.

This code should run out of the box.

Comment: Thanks fameman, i've already updated the description, hope help to understand my question :-)

Comment: it's already working! thank you for your help and experience @fameman !!

Comment: You might want to look into using `mtime`

Comment: I am glad I could help you. I just don't understand wjy my answer got a downvote.

Comment: (Aside: there is no need to add "please comment if you need more help" - readers will know this. As per my trimming signatures etc., we like succinct here).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to reload this file when it changes. You could use something like [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) to know when to reload.